# GetAppenders() returns empty list in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I have the following method that fetches the name of the log file in log4net:

```
private string GetLogFile()
    {
        var repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
        var fileAppender = repo.GetAppenders()
            .OfType<FileAppender>().Single(fa => fa.Name == "LogFileAppender");
        var logFile = fileAppender != null ? fileAppender.File : string.Empty;
        return logFile;
    }
```

This code works fine when I have this code running in a Windows service. But I was given the task to move logging to the main web app. So I referenced log4net in the web app, moved over the config settings, etc. But now when I run the same code the call to GetAppenders() returns an empty list.

Here is the config I have:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="\\MYSERVER\Temp\MYFiles\Log\Log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />      
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
          <level value="ALL" />      
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root>
  </log4net>
```

Is there an extra step in the web app version that I need to do?

Comment: You will also need to configure log4net with `XmlConfigurator.Configure`

Answer (score 4):

It turned out to be something missing in the Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Start method. I needed to add the following line:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are required to also call out the additional config sections at the top of the file, as such:

```
  <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
      <sectionGroup name="common">
          <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
      </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

As well as the addition of the following above your log4net element:

```
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
            <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```

This makes the assumption that you're using Common.Logging and that you are not using a standalone config file (meaning the configuration is within the web.config).

Comment: A) That's only the case if the log4net config is in the web.config file, and should not be used for standalone config files and B) that config would be for using Common.Logging, which is not referenced in the question.

Comment: Did you miss the part where he said that he moved it to a web app, and that is what he is trying to get it to work in?  I had the same issue and solution...